# Semantics of return value of a generator

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem with understanding the semantics of "return" in a generator. I understood it as the final, hence last value.

```
function* gen() {
  yield "foo";
  return "bar";
}

for (const x of gen()) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

This example only prints "foo" and not "bar".

EDIT:

Is there a way to get the returned value of the "done=true" iterator with the "for" syntax, or does it always get lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot get the return value from a `for … of` loop. You could however try

```
function* gen() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  return "done";
}
function* genAndLogResult() {
  const val = yield* gen();
  console.log(val);
}

for (const x of genAndLogResult()) {
  console.log(x + 40);
}
```

Comment: Couldnt one do `yield yield* gen()` ?

Comment: @JonasW. One could, but I wouldn't recommend it. The return value is usually very different from the yielded ones, it is *not* part of the collection. If the author of `gen` didn't put it there, he probably had a good reason for that. I've updated the answer with a better example.

Comment: I don't think this is proper programming whatsoever... This is just a hack. You should not need this in any algorithm in a proper language.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A

> A return statement in a generator, when executed, will make the generator done. If a value is returned, it will be passed back as the value. A generator which has returned will not yield any more values.

It makes sense that the for-loop skips the "done" step. For example:

```
function* gen() { yield "foo" }
const inst = gen()
inst.next() // { done: false, value: "foo" }
inst.next() // { done: true, value: undefined }

function* gen() { yield "foo"; return "bar" }
const inst = gen()
inst.next() // { done: false, value: "foo" }
inst.next() // { done: true, value: "bar" }
```

Since generators don't necessarily have a `return` statement, you wouldn't want the last iteration of the for-loop to always have to deal with the final `undefined` value.

Answer (score 0):

The `yield` keyword is used to pause and resume a generator function.

```
function* gen() {
    yield "foo";
    yield "bar";
}

for (const x of gen()) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

It prints `foo` and `bar`. If you want more details about `yield` click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield)